# Triangulation formula in planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, triangulation

[image]

What is the formula relating number of vertices $v,$  number of sides $s$ in a simple planar graph obtained by triangulating a polygonal region into $n$ triangles? Tried to find a constant out of $v+s-n$ etc. but no luck.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have more luck if you try $v-s+n$.

Comment: Try Euler's formula for a planar graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that

$$
(v+f)=(e+2),\tag{1}
$$

Also we know that your polygonal region is divied into $n$ triangles (faces). In $(1)$ $f=n$. Every face is of size $3$ and if you count around the faces you count each edge twice. All faces have $3$ edges around them, so if there are $f$ faces, hence, there are $3f$ edges counted around them, so $2e=3f$. Putting these together with Euler's formula $(1)$ we get
$$
\frac{2e}{3}=f=(2 + e - v).
$$

Comment: Thanks for reply. But in the figure I drew above I may be missing something. (V,F,E)=(7,7,12);(2E=24, 3F=21), does not tally; Euler relation $V+ F= E+2=14$ satisfies ok.

Comment: @Narasimham the formula does not hold for the figure in the question because it is not a triangulation.  The outer face has length $6$.